# How to reference the active sheet with an Excel database connection

Tags: sql, database-connection, excel-2010

Can anyone show me how to dynamically reference the current file in a Database Connection in Excel.

I am trying to create a tool in Excel 2010 that uses Excel's Database Connections and SQL functionality to perform an INNER JOIN.  I want to compare two lists and provide a third list of common data elements.

I have been able to create a database connection to the current file (using a hard coded reference) and was able to get the INNER JOIN to work.  The tricky bit is that I need to share this tool with others and need a way to dynamically reference the file in the connection string as well as the command text (current file location is "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\thisFile.xlsx" where "UserName" changes with each user).  Does anyone know how to do this?

For those who love VBA and macros -- I already know how to do this with an Excel macro but I do not want to have a macro-enabled Excel file.  I am also going to expand this tools functionality to include LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, etc. so it will get to be a pain to change the connection string on each connection for each user...

Comment: Have you tried using relative paths, instead of absolute?

Comment: That is what I wanted to do but I wasn't sure how to do this.  I kept gettings errors when I tried to use "Workbook.ActiveSheet" in place of my file name.